# Calculating the pixel change between two raster files

Tags: python, arcgis-pro

I have two raster files of Blue band having the same cell size, row and column. I want to find the change in each pixel of raster files. Is there a way to do this in Python or ArcGIS?

I have cell size= 31*30m, Row= 500 and column = 7000.

Comment: Subtract them. Whatever tool you are using will have some sort of way of operating on rasters and "subtract" or "difference" will be there. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the change detection wizard tool in ArcgGis pro tool to calculate change..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm) if you have Spatial Analyst extension.

If not you can use arcpy to convert the raster to numpy arrays, subtract, write to raster. Look at the code samples for [RasterToNumpyArray](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) and [NumPyArrayToRaster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/numpyarraytoraster-function.htm)

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

rasterfile1 = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\rasters\B02_10m.jp2"
rasterfile2 = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\rasters\B04_10m.jp2"

outraster = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\rasters\difference5.tif" #Output difference raster
arcpy.env.compression = 'LZW' #Set the compression of the output
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.Describe(rasterfile1).spatialReference #Set the coordinate system

raster1 = arcpy.Raster(rasterfile1)
raster2 = arcpy.Raster(rasterfile2)

# Get input Raster properties
lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(raster1.extent.XMin,raster1.extent.YMin)
cellSize = raster1.meanCellWidth

#Convert rasters to numpy arrays
arr1 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster1, nodata_to_value=-999)
arr2 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster2, nodata_to_value=-999)

#Calculate change
difference = arr2-arr1

#Convert Array to raster (keep the origin and cellsize the same as the input)
newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(difference, lowerLeft, cellSize, value_to_nodata=-999)
newRaster.save(outraster)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will try this in my case study. However, I used the change detection wizard tool in ArcGis pro and was able to calculate difference in pixel each pixel value